# TypeError: x and y must have the same dtype, got tf.float32 != tf.int64 in custom loss function keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, loss-function

I am implementing the custom loss function and my code is as below:

```
def seedloss(y_true,y_pred):
        count = tf.count_nonzero(y_pred)
        loss = K.log(y_pred)
        logval = tf.where(tf.is_inf(loss), tf.zeros_like(loss), loss)
        loss = -(K.sum(logval,axis=(1,2,3))/count)
        return loss
```

But I am getting the below error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "trainrefinenet.py", line 69, in <module>
    refinenet_model.compile(optimizer = Adam(lr=lr_init), loss = seedloss, metrics = [iou_coef])
  File "/home/ssindhu/deeplab_env/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 229, in compile
    self.total_loss = self._prepare_total_loss(masks)
  File "/home/ssindhu/deeplab_env/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 692, in _prepare_total_loss
    y_true, y_pred, sample_weight=sample_weight)
  File "/home/ssindhu/deeplab_env/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/keras/losses.py", line 71, in __call__
    losses = self.call(y_true, y_pred)
  File "/home/ssindhu/deeplab_env/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/keras/losses.py", line 132, in call
    return self.fn(y_true, y_pred, **self._fn_kwargs)
  File "/home/ssindhu/metrics.py", line 32, in seedloss
    loss = -(K.sum(logval,axis=(1,2,3),keepdims=True)/count)
  File "/home/ssindhu/deeplab_env/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/math_ops.py", line 884, in binary_op_wrapper
    return func(x, y, name=name)
  File "/home/ssindhu/deeplab_env/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/math_ops.py", line 982, in _truediv_python3
    (x_dtype, y_dtype))
TypeError: x and y must have the same dtype, got tf.float32 != tf.int64
```

I tried to to `K.cast` for int64 but still I am getting the same error. Can someone help me in understanding reason behind this error and how to resolve this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is withing the `count` tensor as its type is `tf.int64` by default according to the official documentation [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/math/count_nonzero).

You can solve this issue by setting the tensor type like so:

```
count = tf.count_nonzero(np.array([1, 2, 0]), dtype=tf.float32)
```

Comment: Thank you!! The error is gone. But I am getting `nan` loss while training. any inputs for that please?

Comment: make sure `count` is not zero?

Comment: I added a constant to count to make sure it's not zero but still I have the same issue.

Comment: What is the shape of `logval`? And does it contain any `nan` values??

Comment: `logval` has no `nan`, i am actually replacing `nan` with zero and storing it in `logval`. The shape of `logval` is `(1,224,224,20)` which is the size of `y_pred` for a batch size of 1.